# NgController scope inherit after update 0.9.9

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have error after update to Angular 0.9.10.

```dart
=== index.html ====
...
<body ng-app>
  <div ng-hide="true" class="border well loading">Wait ...</div>
  <div main-controller ng-cloak>
  ...
  </div>
</body>

=== main.dart ===
@NgController(
  selector: '[main-controller]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MainController { 
  ...
  MainController (Scope scope) {
  scope.context['msg'] = "abc";
  }
}

=== other.dart ===
@NgController(
  selector: '[other-controller]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class OtherController { 
  ...
  Scope scope; 
  OtherController (Scope _scope) {
  this.scope = _scope;
  print("msg => $this.scope.context['msg']"); // I want print msg => abc here 
  }
}
```

On angular version < 0.9.8 it print msg => abc but after update to 0.9.10 it is null.

I know new notice of NgController : Controllers create a new scope at the element. Is it a new on 0.9.9 ?

Does scope of controller like component ? Because I read AngularDart tutorial ch03 : "Components create their own scope hierarchy that is invisible from the outside world. They don’t have direct access to the app’s scope, nor does the app have direct access to a component’s scope."

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you apply your `other-controller` in HTML.

Comment: I have mainRouterInitializer, it has defaultRoute to other.html.    <div other-controller class="container">
 ...
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some curly braces

```dart
 print("msg => $this.scope.context['msg']");  // wrong
 print("msg => ${this.scope.context['msg']}"); // evaluates the entire expression not only `this`
```